# How to prove that this limit is undefined?

Tags: limits

> Prove that $$\lim_{x\to 0} {x\over \sin {1\over x}}$$
>   is not defined

How could I do this? I know that as $x$ approaches 0 the function $\sin{1\over x}$ vibrates more frequently, but how should I write out the proof formally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Make use of the fact that $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ is an oscillatory function about 0 while finding the limit by $\epsilon- \delta$ definition and show that you cannot find a suitable $\delta$ near $0$.